# How can I deny @everyone and allow the author to view the channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've been tinkering around with this for a while, and I have never done permission based channel creation. I am working on a ticket function for my bot and I can't quite seem to get it working. The idea is to create a channel with set permissions named the message.author entire tag with the permissions set to only allow the message.author to see the channel. For some reason I keep running into an error. How can I fix this? I've defined the everyone role and message.author should already be defined. Am I missing something?

```js
if (message.channel.type !== "text") {
  let active = db.fetch(`support_${message.author.id}`)
  let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('took out ID')
  let channel, found = true

  try {
    if (active) client.channels.cache.get(active.channelID).guild
  } catch (e) {
    found = false;
  }

  if(!active || !found) {
    active = {}

    let everyoneRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === '@everyone');

    channel = await guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}-${message.author.discriminator}`, {
      parent: 'took out ID',
      topic: `Support for ${message.author.tag} | ID: ${message.author.id}`,
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: everyoneRole.id,
          deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
      ],
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`roles.everyone`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone) that returns the `@everyone` role of the guild or simply use the [guild's ID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=id). Also, your overwrites are incorrect. It should contain two objects; one that denies views for everyone, and one that allows it for the member who sent the message.

Any of these will work:

```js
let permissionOverwrites = [
  {
    id: message.guild.roles.everyone.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
  {
    id: message.author.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
];

let channel = await guild.channels.create(
  `${message.author.username}-${message.author.discriminator}`,
  {
    parent: 'took out ID',
    topic: `Support for ${message.author.tag} | ID: ${message.author.id}`,
    permissionOverwrites,
  },
);
```

Or:

```js
let permissionOverwrites = [
  {
    id: message.guild.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
  {
    id: message.author.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
];

let channel = await guild.channels.create(
  `${message.author.username}-${message.author.discriminator}`,
  {
    parent: 'took out ID',
    topic: `Support for ${message.author.tag} | ID: ${message.author.id}`,
    permissionOverwrites,
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let everyoneRole = message.guild.id;
```

The role for `@everyone` is the same as the guild id.